# Why Floating action button Behind the BottomBar

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want the Floating Action Button in the middle of the BottomBar and the front, not on the back, please guide me to solve this problem My layer codes are as follows...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_behavior="helpers."
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Relative layout arrange views one above one so views are arranged by the order you declared in xml**

So change your order of your view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:elevation="0dp"
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
app:elevation="8dp"
app:fabSize="normal"
app:layout_behavior="helpers."
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
```

Hope it helps..!

**EDITED**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar_"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_tabs" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @HadiKhezrpor Its happen bcoz of your custom bottom bar try to put bottom bar under one layout will fix it. See edited

Comment: @HadiKhezrpor Welcome glad to help happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try change the position of FAB to below bottom bar.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

 <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />



<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:elevation="0dp"
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
app:elevation="8dp"
app:fabSize="normal"
app:layout_behavior="helpers."
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Also make sure the [default elevation](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#default-elevations) of fab less (6) than bottom bar(8) so you need to take care of that too.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. Please correct my code