# Android bottomnavigation view item icon size

Tags: android, xml

I need to do a bottom navigation view in Android like this: [image: what i want]
I tried, and now I have something like this: [image: what i have]

How can I increase size of the + icon? It will be static and bigger then another icons all the time. Other icons will change color when activated, but the size will remain the same.

Activity xml:

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemBackground="@color/white"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp" />
```

Bottom navigation view xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="@string/home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_notification"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notification"
    android:title="@string/notification"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title=" "
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:itemIconSize="50px"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_schedule"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="@string/schedule"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_schedule"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="@string/profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying can be achieved by using a 'Floating Action Button' on top of the Bottom Bar.
The third item in your Bottom Bar can then just be a placeholder. No action, name and icon on it.

A layout for example with a Floating Action Button on top is presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026043/why-floating-action-button-behind-the-bottombar) post, see the post for more information regarding possibly the same issue you are facing.

You could also take a look at [this](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708). The newer Bottom Bar of Google that includes functionality with a Floating Action Button.